# Android - Align a view with the text of a checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, alignment, size

I have an EditText below a Checkbox.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/confirmation_receipt"
        style="@style/AppTheme.Checkbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/content_margin_s"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:text="@string/bill_payment_confirmation_receipt" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/confirmation_receipt_customer_email"
        style="@style/AppTheme.EditText.Info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/content_margin_xxxl"
        android:hint="@string/bill_payment_confirmation_receipt_customer_email_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textNoSuggestions"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Checking the checkbox reveals the EditText.

I would like to align the EditText view with the text of the checkbox.
[image]

The problem is that I don't know the exact size of the checkbox icon. And oddly, its size changes depending on the device. Is there a way to align these 2 texts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple hack to achieve this. What I have done is separated the checkbox and it's text to a separate textview. Then set the same left margin value to the newly added textview and the edittext

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/bill_payment_confirmation_receipt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/confirmation_receipt"
        style="@style/AppTheme.Checkbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/confirmation_receipt_customer_email"
    style="@style/AppTheme.EditText.Info"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:hint="@string/bill_payment_confirmation_receipt_customer_email_hint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textNoSuggestions"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```